# Constructing a for loop for picking the portfolios on the efficient frontier

Tags: r, loops

[image]

I constructed 10,000 random portfolios for portfolio optimization. The output looks something like this: (only the first three rows)

```
AMZN   TSLA   GOOG  AAPL MSFT  Return Risk SharpeRatio
```

1 0.0869  0.238  0.124  0.267 0.284    0.372 0.255        1.46

2 0.0184 0.213  0.361  0.223 0.185    0.339 0.248        1.37

3 0.346  0.164  0.245  0.207 0.0372   0.354 0.246        1.44

Now I would like to choose only the portfolios that are on the efficient frontier, i.e only the portfolios that have the best risk return ratios. I was thinking that a for loop would be the best way to do so, I'm not that advanced in R so I can't think of a better way. So, the loop I was thinking would go through all the portfolios, and for each return value it would choose the one with the lowest risk.

So the idea for the loop: for each return value, pick the portfolio with the lowest risk and place it in some storage

Like I said, I'm not that advanced in R so I don't know how to code the loop. I'd appreciate if someone could help me in constructing the loop or suggest a better way to do the task.

Edit: I added the image to clarify what I'm trying to do. There are all the 10,000 portfolios plotted. I would like to pick all the portfolios on the efficient frontier which is the outer side of the figure. So, as an example, for return i, pick up the portfolio with the lowest return which is j. And I would like to do this for all the return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used daily returns for five years for the stocks you show to calculate risk and returns (standard deviataions) for 50,000 random portfolios.  These portfolios seems to have similar risks and returns as you show for your portfolio.

```
  AMZN   TSLA   GOOG   AAPL   MSFT Return  Risk SharpeRatio 
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1 0.371  0.149  0.214  0.153  0.113   0.344 0.265        1.30
2 0.190  0.0155 0.491  0.289  0.0135  0.264 0.249        1.06
3 0.0845 0.264  0.116  0.241  0.295   0.389 0.289        1.35
4 0.222  0.296  0.292  0.156  0.0331  0.376 0.293        1.28
5 0.0181 0.182  0.306  0.208  0.286   0.336 0.268        1.25
```

The code below finds the efficient frontier for these portfolios by dividing the range of risks into intervals each .01 wide and then grouping the portfolios by interval.  The portfolios on the efficient frontier are the ones with the maximum return in each interval.

The efficient frontier and the weights for the efficient portfolios are then plotted.

```
#
#  Plot efficient frontier
#
   ports
#  
# Divide Risk dimension into .01 length intervals,
# group by risk interval, and 
# assign an id to each portfolio in the interval
#
   port_intvl <-  ports %>% 
                mutate(Risk_intvl = findInterval(x=Risk, vec = seq(.01, .5, .01))) %>%
                group_by(Risk_intvl) %>% 
                mutate(Risk_intvl_id = 1:n() )
#
# Form the efficient frontier by finding, for each Risk interval, the portfolio 
# with max Return 
#  
   eff_front <- port_intvl  %>% 
           mutate(num_samples = n(),
                  Intvl_max_ret_id = which.max(Return),
                  eff_Return = Return[Intvl_max_ret_id],
                  eff_Risk = Risk[Intvl_max_ret_id]) %>%
           filter(Risk_intvl_id == Intvl_max_ret_id) %>% arrange(Risk_intvl)
#
# plot the efficient frontier and tickers
#
    eff_front %>% ggplot() +
                geom_point(data = ports, aes(x = Risk, y = Return,
                      color = SharpeRatio)) +
                geom_line(aes(x = eff_Risk, y = eff_Return),
                        color = "red", size = 1.05) +
                geom_point(data = ticker_return_ann,
                       aes(x = Risk, y = Return), color = "tan") +
                geom_text(data = ticker_return_ann,
                       aes(x = Risk, y = Return, label = Ticker),
                       color = "tan", vjust = -.9, fontface = "bold" ) +
                scale_color_gradient(low = "#CAD7EE", high = "#2C4E8C") +
                scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
                scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,
                                expand = expansion(add = c(.01,.03))) +
                labs(title = "Efficient Frontier", 
                    x = "Risk", y = "Return") +
                theme_bw() + 
                theme(title = element_text(size = 14,face = "bold.italic" ),
                     axis.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "plain"),
                   legend.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "plain"))

#
#  plot portfolio weights
#
   eff_front_ports_plot <- eff_front_ports %>% pivot_longer(cols = tickers, names_to = 
             "Tickers",values_to = "Portfolio_Weight") 
   eff_front_ports_plot %>% ggplot(aes(x = Return, y = Portfolio_Weight, color = 
             Tickers)) +
               geom_line(size = 1.05) +
               geom_text(data = eff_front_ports_plot %>% filter(Risk == min(Risk)),
                         aes(x = Return, y = Portfolio_Weight, label = Tickers), hjust = 1.1) +
               scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(.025,.01)),
                                              labels = scales::percent) +
               scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,
                                              expand = expansion(add = c(.01,.03))) +
               scale_color_brewer(type = "div", palette = "Set1",
                                              guide = NULL) +
               theme_bw() +
               facet_wrap(facets = vars(Tickers))
```

which generates the following Efficient Frontier chart.  The minimum of the efficient frontier would be an all GOOG portfolio and the maximum one with all TSLA.

[image]